# Not able to query businesshour name from case object

Tags: soql, case

Currently I am using this I am able to businesshourId but business hour name. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
  AccountId,Account_Name__c,
  BusinessHoursId,
  Case_ID__c,
  SLO__c,
  Support_Level__c,
  Support_Time_Zone__c

  FROM Case where ID in 
  (SELECT CaseId FROM CaseMilestone
  where IsViolated = TRUE
  and MilestoneTypeId = '')
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? What have you tried?

Comment: I am not getting any error its just displaying BusinesshourId not name. I need BusinessHour name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pull `BusinessHours.Name`:

```
SELECT BusinessHours.Name FROM Case
```

If you want more information about how to use table joins in SOQL, I recommend you read [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com), and specifically this type of query is a **[`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join)**.